# Google chart not display on using json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-visualization

I am using google chart api.I use json data to bind with datatabel in google chart.I call json data through ajax call.Json data comes properly then i parse this data and save it into array.When I give the array value to DataTabel of x axis then google chart not display.please help me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var Name = [];
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "NewDashboard.aspx/DisplayData",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {

                var contact = JSON.parse(result.d);
                for (var i = 0; i < contact.length; i++) {

                    Name.push([contact[i].VehicleName]);

                }




                var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                    chartType: 'ColumnChart',
                    dataTable: [['',Name[0], Name[1],Name[3]s],
                  ['', 700, 300, 400]],
                    options: { 'title': 'Countries' },
                    containerId: 'visualization'
                });

                wrapper.draw();

            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        }); 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a typo error. Use

```
var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                    chartType: 'ColumnChart',
                    dataTable: [['',Name[0], Name[1],Name[3]],
                  ['', 700, 300, 400]],
                    options: { 'title': 'Countries' },
                    containerId: 'visualization'
                });
```

and try this format to prevent mistakes:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          [title, 'countries'],
          [Name[0],  1000],
          [Name[1],  1170],
        ]);
```

Comment: I think json structure is not according to chart. Try it with registering error event with `wrapper` variable.

Comment: Your DOM must be similar to this: `<div id="visualization" style="height:500px;width:500px;"></div> `

Comment: Use JSON parsing as `var contact = result["d"];` or `var contact = result.d;

for(var key in contact) {
  Name.push(key.VehicleName);
}`